# jQuery to change <td> values using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, each

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="table-name">
    <tr><td id="td-name">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="td-name">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="td-name">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="td-name">something</td></tr>
</table>
```

And I'm trying to change the "something" value using jQuery like this:

```
$("#table-name #td-name").each(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.asp",
    data: $(this).html()        
    }).done(function r(returnOfASP) {
        $(this).html(returnOfASP);
    });         
});
```

It does database query with an "file.asp". "something" is the parameter of the database query. "file.asp" return the query correctly, but I can't change the `<td>` value (html). I suppose `$(this)` in "done" of Ajax is not correct, but I don't know what to do.

Comment: can't you give each table data a unique id? that would make things much easier for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your jQuery code like so:

```
$("#table-name td").each(function () {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.asp",
        data: $(this).html()        
    }).done(function r(returnOfASP) {
    $(self).html(returnOfASP);
    });         
});
```

You can't have multiple id's on a page which could be messing up your selector. You could use classes instead if you want to filter more. Also, saving `this` out to variable might take care of that issue.

You also had an extra `});` that shouldn't have been there after `$(this).html()`

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to delegate execution in the different context. In your case it's parent.

```
$("#table-name #td-name").each(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.asp",
        data: $(this).html()        
    }).done($.proxy(function(response) { $(this).html(returnOfASP); }, this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

your td's need unique id's or it should be called class.

If you want to loop over them then give the td  class

```
<table id="table-name">
    <tr><td class="tdName">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="tdName">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="tdName">something</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="tdName">something</td></tr>
</table>
```

Javascript testing

```
$("#table-name .tdName").each(function () {
    // do code in here

    // test output in firebug with
    console.log($(this));
});
```